# How to change UISearchBar Textfield Default Placeholder "Search" to "Enter city name..."

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to implement a simple search project. I have taken a `TableViewController` and assigned the `UISearchBar` in StoryBoard. I assigned placeholder text in Attributes Inspector "placeholder section". When I ran the project placeholder text appeared perfectly.

Slowly I started implementing the search methods. I have been following a tutorial, at one point of time I had to add

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

in ViewDidLoad. Then I am not able see the placeholder which I gave in storyboard instead I am seeing a default placeholder "Search".

After testing few times I figured that above line giving that default "search" placeholder. I deleted that line and ran the project once again, then I could see the placeholder which I gave in storyboard but search functionality is not working(My tableview is not getting updated with search text).

Q1: What exactly the above line is doing ?

Q2: I want to add custom placeholder text to UISearchBar ? How I can do it ?

tutorial link: https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial

```
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
definesPresentationContext = true
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad` set the `placeholder` property of `UISearchBar` for that.

```
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Enter City"
```

Comment: Can you explain why my storyboard placeholder text was not appearing ?

Comment: @Karen Welcome mate :) I don't know how you are setting it in storyboard.

Comment: I did accept your answer... Like I said above I have assigned placeholder text in attribute inspector.

Comment: @Karen Are you having any other code of `searchController` in your `viewDidLoad` if yes then add that also.

Comment: No I do not have any other code apart from those above four lines, with your answer I added placeholder text as 5th line.

Comment: @Karen Can you show your storyboard also where you have declared `searchController`?

Comment: I declared controller in class Properties      let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

Comment: @Karen Show your storyboard screenshot

Comment: how to attach screenshot here I mean comment section ?

Comment: @Karen Edit your question and add screenshot.